# Undo or restore git filter-repo command

Tags: github

In the attempt to get rid of a large history file (.RDataTmp >> 100 Mb) that was causing GitHub to fail its synchronization, I used the git filter-repo command, and specifically the following:

```
User@mac MainDirectory % git filter-repo --path manuscript/code/.RDataTmp--invert-paths
```

This resulted in the following messages:

```
Parsed 142 commits
New history written in 0.92 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Updating files: 100% (13768/13768), done.
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 5.80 seconds.
```

After this I tried to synch the updated files with the repository, with the following commands:

```
(base) User@Mac MainDirectory % git stage .
(base) User@Mac MainDirectory % git commit -m "updates"
```

This had the following result

```
[master (root-commit) a413463] updates
57 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

The it enter into a `create mode 100644` with those 57 files and after this I pushed the repo. The result was a failed push, with the message:

> "fatal: No configured push destination. Either specify the URL from
> the command-line or configure a remote repository using git remote add
>   and then push using the remote name"

I then opened GitHub Desktop and pushed to another repository (new one), thinking that all my offline files would have been pushed online in the updated repository.

The conclusion is that I now have a bunch of folders, almost none of the files I had and no history from either the original repo or the new-named one.

Is there a way to revert this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not any git repository assigned to the project. Try creating the git  repository from the beginning for your porject.
Or, if you had already created the repository for the project, you are trying to push it from the wrong directory, move to the right directory before trying pushing it.